# Can WebAuthN be used to identify an individual?

Tags: webapi, webauthn

I'm wondering whether WebAuthN APIs can be used to identify an individual. Do any of the following hold

- Can the authenticator ever return info about the individual e.g. First name, email etc
- Will the authenticator always give us the same ID back for Alice when she uses this device regardless of which website I'm requesting from?
- Will different devices ever give back the same ID for the same user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can the authenticator ever return info about the individual e.g. First name, email etc

It *can* if you set personally-identifying information to the value of `user.id` in the options you pass to `navigator.credentials.create()`. Also referred to as the "user handle", the spec includes a section specifically about how this value is [one way the API can leak personally-identifying information if you're not careful what value you set `user.id` to](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-user-handle-privacy).

> Will the authenticator always give us the same ID back for Alice when she uses this device regardless of which website I'm requesting from?

The authenticator will *not* give back the same ID on every website. Every successful invocation of `navigator.credentials.create()` generates a unique credential bound to the website, meaning every website would have to use the same value for Alice's internal user ID for this to even have a chance of happening. And for any given website the authenticator only gives back the value of `user.id` (as passed into `navigator.credentials.create()`) [as `userHandle` in the response from `navigator.credentials.get()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#iface-authenticatorassertionresponse) when Alice logs into that site.

> Will different devices ever give back the same ID for the same user?

Different registered authenticators *would* give back the same ID for Alice provided you specify the same value for `user.id` whenever Alice registers an authenticator.

Comment: Not sure I got the terminology correct here... so the authenticator would be say apple face id or apple touch id. Can applereturn me info about the user who is authenticating?

Comment: Touch ID and Face ID will indeed give you back the value of `user.id`, specified during registration, as `userHandle` in the response returned from `navigator.credentials.get()`. Is that what you mean?